# Regex to validate both web and LDAP url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am creating a Regex `^(http://|https://|ldap://|ldaps://){1}[\S]*$` to validate these types of URL

- http://stackoverflow.com
- http://www.stackoverflow.com
- https://stackoverflow.com?q=regular+expr=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a
- ldap://192.442.242.244:389

It should not validate

- wrong urls
- http://wwsw.stackoverflow.com
- ldap://192.442.242.244:389asd
- ldap://192.442.242asd.244:389

I will use it for javascript

Comment: `ldap://192.442.242.244:389` is not valid IP.

Answer (score 3):

```
m{ (?:ldap|http)s?://                   # Scheme

(?:(?!.*\d[/?:]) [a-z0-9\-._~%]+      | # IPv4 host (forbid ending with digit)
   # IP (yep, I've copied this regexp)
   (?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])
   \[[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\] ) # or IPv6 host

(?::\d+)?                            # Port

(?:

  [/?]                               # Slash or question mark

  [-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*        # URL itself

)? # Technically, trailing / is required in URLs, but many browser implementations ignore it when accepting those
                                                }ix
```

This regular expression should work with `/ix`. As JS doesn't include `/x` modifier, I'm going to include version without it.

```
/(?:ldap|http)s?:\/\/(?:(?!.*\d[\/?:])[a-z0-9\-._~%]+|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\[[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])(?::\d+)?(?:[\/?][\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*)?/i
```

Note that a lot of characters are allowed in HTTP URLs without escaping using `%` mark. You probably wouldn't want URL to not pass just because it contains allowed in URLs character `*` :).

Comment: @imrantariq: OK, I've added intentional breaking of HTTP standard by allowing `?` without slash. By the way, `http://wwsw.stackoverflow.com` is technically valid URL. It's entirely possible to make such subdomain. Checking if URL exists is outside of scope of regexpes - it requires actual network connection.

Answer (score 0):

for IPs you can use
`^(http://|https://|ldap://|ldaps://)((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}(:\\d{1,5})?)$`
But for other urls... You have to check if site responds. Because it can be a site say `wwsw.com` and how should your regex know if it's a real site or no? there can be a real site with subdomain wwsw.
**EDIT:**
GlitchMr is right. For IPv4 use his regex.